# How to assign the mixin $variable in scss file to an html element's class

Tags: angular-material2, scss-mixins

In my component.scss file, I have got mixin variable, I'm trying to set the ripple color for a div element.

if I set a direct color value **eg: [matRippleColor]="red"** in the HTML, The ripple color is applied and **working**.

however, if I give the **mixin variable's name** or a **scss class name** to the [matRipplecolor], the ripple color is **not applied**.

> **component.scss** flie

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@mixin dashboard-component-theme($bg-ripple) {

    .rippleCOLOR {
        background-color: $bg-ripple;
        color: $bg-ripple;
    }
}
```

> **component.html** flie

```
<!-- WORKING: Direct Color value -->
<div matRipple [matRippleColor]="red"> Some text </div>


<!-- NOT WORKING: mixin variable -->
<div matRipple [matRippleColor]="$bg-ripple"> Some text </div>

<!-- NOT WORKING: scss class name -->
<div matRipple [matRippleColor]="rippleCOLOR"> Some text </div>
```

need to set the ripple color from a mixin variable in the scss file

Comment: AFAIK, you can only pass a valid CSS color code. (For example, you can use `red` or `rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)`.)

Answer (score 1):

you can't use scss in HTML document/element, since you need to compile it into css..

some youtube tutorial below.. [scss install and compile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M06tofS0uPU)

was actually wierd, as i was so angry long ago why my scss is not working.. i thought it was all about server setup :S

Comment: yeah.. me too frustrated.. and after a while did some dirty workaround and it helped..

Comment: i hope that youtube video helps you :) have fun programming